# Cutting the tail of inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

By [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we know that if $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are $n$ sets, then $$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right|=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\left(\sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n}|A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}|\right).$$

I wonder, what if we cut the outer sum on the right to just $\sum_{k=1}^r$ for some $r\leq n$? Will we guarantee inequality in one way or the other?

For $r=1$, it is obvious by [Boole's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality) that the left-hand side is $\leq$ the right-hand side.

I think that the same should hold for $r$ odd, and the reverse inequality should hold for $r$ even. Any proof/counterexamples for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aren't these the [Bonferroni inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole's_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities), which are in the same Wikipedia article that you linked to in your question? [This old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208766/how-to-prove-bonferroni-inequalities) asked "How to prove Bonferroni inequalities"; **Did's  answer** gives some hints:

> A proof is [there](http://planetmath.org/proofofbonferroniinequalities). The main idea is that this is the integrated version of analogous pointwise inequalities and that, for every $k$, 
>   $$
> S_k=\mathbb E\left({T\choose k}\right),\qquad T=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf 1_{A_i}.
> $$
>   Hence the result follows from the stronger inequalities asserting that, for every positive integer $N$,
>   $$
> \sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^ia_i,\qquad a_i={N\choose i},
> $$
>   is nonnegative when $k$ is even and nonpositive when $k$ is odd. In turn, this fact follows from the properties that the sequence $(a_i)_{0\leqslant i\leqslant N}$ is unimodal and that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^N(-1)^ia_i=0$.

Comment: No reason to downvote; better to see whether OP can discuss relation of Bonferroni to the question at hand.

Comment: I think it's just the same as the Bonferroni you linked to, just the count replaced by probability. How do you prove Bonferroni though?

Comment: The link in my answer is [resurrected](http://planetmath.org/proofofbonferroniinequalities) (and I took the liberty to modify your answer accordingly).