# Problem in derivation of Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a problem in understanding the derivation of the  Poisson Process in the second edition of Klenke "Probability Theory". At the end of page 124 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuSus.png)), he explains the meaning of P5 that is $\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}P[N_\epsilon\geq 2]=0$, by defining 
$$\lambda=\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}P[N_\epsilon\geq 2].$$

And writes: For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$
P[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2]\geq\lfloor\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}\rfloor P[N_{\epsilon}\geq2]-\lfloor\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}\rfloor^{2}P[N_{\epsilon}\geq2]^{2}.
$$
Hence, 
$$2^n P[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2]\geq \lambda-2^{-n}\lambda^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \lambda.$$

I cannot fully derive none of the above inequalities.

For the first one this is what I did:

Let $R_{n,\epsilon}\triangleq\lfloor\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}\rfloor$
and $\underline{R}_{n,\epsilon}\triangleq2^{-n}\mod\epsilon$, so
that $2^{-n}=R_{n,\epsilon}\epsilon+\underline{R}_{n,\epsilon}$,
with $0\leq\underline{R}_{n,\epsilon}<\epsilon.$ We use the first
three proprieties P1, P2, and P3 to derive the above relation as follows,

$$\begin{align*}
P[N_{2^{-n}}\geq2]= & P\left[N_{\bigcup_{r=0}^{R_{n,\epsilon}-1}(r\epsilon,(r+1)\epsilon]\cup(R_{n,\epsilon}\epsilon,2^{-n}]}\geq2\right]=P\left[\sum_{r=0}^{R_{n,\epsilon}-1}N_{(r\epsilon,(r+1)\epsilon]}+N_{(R_{n,\epsilon}\epsilon,2^{-n}]}\geq2\right]\\
\geq & P\left[\bigcup_{r=0}^{R_{n,\epsilon}-1}\left\{ N_{(r\epsilon,(r+1)\epsilon]}\geq2\right\} \right]=R_{n,\epsilon}P\left[N_{(r\epsilon,(r+1)\epsilon]}\geq2\right]=\lfloor\frac{2^{-n}}{\epsilon}\rfloor P\left[N_{\epsilon}\geq2\right]
\end{align*},$$

Which only gives the first term of the inequality but not the second squared term. Given the second line we do not really need it as it goes to 0 by taking $n$ to infinity, but I am afraid I might have done a mistake in the above result.

I appreciate if someone could verify it and also explains how the second relation after the "hence" comes about (I can see that but not exactly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For notational convenience, write $A_r := \left\{ N_{(r\epsilon,(r+1)\epsilon]}\geq2\right\} $. The argument for the first inequality goes like this:
$$
P(N_{2^{-n}}\ge2)\stackrel{(1)}\ge 
P(\bigcup_r A_r)\stackrel{(2)}\ge \sum_r P(A_r) - \sum_{r<s}P(A_r\cap A_s)
$$
In the above, (1) follows because the event $\bigcup_rA_r$ implies the event $\{N_{2^{-n}}\ge2\}$. Inequality (2) is a [Bonferroni inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208766/how-to-prove-bonferroni-inequalities), namely the one obtained by truncating inclusion-exclusion at two terms. Next, replace $\sum_r P(A_r)$ with $R_{n,\epsilon}P(A_0)$ as you've done. Simplify $\sum_{r<s}P(A_r\cap A_s)$ to $\sum_{r<s}P(A_r)P(A_s)=\sum_{r<s}P(A_0)^2$ by properties P3 and P2; and clearly $\sum_{r<s}P(A_0)^2$ is bounded above by $R_{N,\epsilon}^2$ times $P(A_0)^2$, which completes the proof.

As for the second inequality, you multiply the first inequality through by $2^n$ (for fixed $n$), then apply $\limsup$, which preserves the inequality. Then bound the RHS of the result using the inequality $$\limsup (a_\epsilon-b_\epsilon)\ge \limsup a_\epsilon - \limsup b_\epsilon,\tag3$$ (which follows from $\limsup (x_\epsilon + y_\epsilon)\le \limsup x_\epsilon + \limsup y_\epsilon$). Finally use P5 to argue that the limsups on the RHS of (3) are equal to the stated values.

For example, to see why
$$\limsup_\epsilon 2^n\epsilon\lfloor 2^{-n}/\epsilon\rfloor \frac1\epsilon P(N_\epsilon\ge2)=\lambda,$$
you can use 
 the inequality $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$ to argue that $2^n\epsilon\lfloor 2^{-n}/\epsilon\rfloor\to1$ as $\epsilon\to0$. (Remember $n$ is still fixed.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have one question regarding the second inequality. When we multiply the first inequality by  $2^n$, what happens to the floor function? It appears to me that we cannot just simplify $2^n\lfloor 2^{-n}/\epsilon\rfloor$ to $1/\epsilon$ and taking away the floor function increases the RHS of the first inequality. Would you please explain that part?

Comment: @Soufa Right, you cannot just take away the floor function. See my edit for a careful argument.

Comment: Thanks!, another question if I may. The book uses $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n P[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2]=\lambda$, in the next page. However, the second inequality is only from below. I guess we need we need an argument like $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \lambda-2^{-n}\lambda^2\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} 2^nP[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2] \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} 2^nP[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2]\leq \lambda.$$ 
 I guess we have $\limsup_{n\to\infty} 2^nP[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2]= \lambda$, since if the limsup is true for $\epsilon\to 0$ it is true for any sequence, which here happens to be $2^{-n}$. Am I right?

Comment: @Soufa Your argument that $\lim_{n\to\infty}=\lambda$ is correct! As to your second point, it is clear that the limsup along a sequence is less than or equal to the limsup as $\epsilon\to0$, but it can be *strictly* less (think of an example!) . To prevent the strictly less possibility, it is enough to show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\ge\limsup_{\epsilon\to0}$, as the author has done. There would be no need for this entire exercise if the limsup along a sequence always equals the limsup as $\epsilon\to0$!

Comment: @Soufa ... although I don't know what's happening on the next page. What is the end result?

Comment: Thanks got it! I can see that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} 2^nP[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2]$ could be strictly less than $\lambda$ (I guess one example would be the typical $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ when $x\to0$ and we pick a sequence like $\frac{1}{2n\pi}$). But here either using $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \lambda-2^{-n}\lambda^2\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} 2^nP[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2] $ or taking $\limsup$ of the original inequality brings us home. ... The book uses $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n P[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2]=\lambda$ to claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1- P[N_{2^{-n}}\geq 2])^{2^n}=e^{-\lambda}$. Thanks again!